# Different regression coefficients in R and Excel

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients, linear, excel

Asking a separate question because whilst this has been answered for polynomial regression the solution doesn't work for me.

I'm performing a simple linear regression. Both R and Excel give the same P values, $R^2$ values and F statistics, but they give different coefficients (and therefore equations to put on the graph?)

This is the data:

> `suva Std dev heather sedge   sphagnum
>   12.880545   0.061156645 0.15    0.525   0
>   7.098873327 0.026878039 0.2275  0   0
>   8.660688381 0.04037841  0.425   0.25    0
>   7.734546932 0.021618446 0.225   0.3875  0
>   16.70696048 0.103626684 0.15    0.075   0
>   9.763315183 0.013387158 0.25    0.075   0
>   12.91735434 0.008076468 0.22    0.22    0
>   19.94153851 0.150798057 0.0375  0.35    0.225
>   17.25115559 0.052229596 0.0625  0.2625  0.225
>   15.38596941 0.05429447  0.1125  0.45    0.025
>   15.53714185 0.05933884  0.1625  0.525   0.0625
>   14.11551229 0.064579437 0.1875  0.35    0.1375
>   14.88575569 0.0189853   0.3375  0.3 0
>   12.32229733 0.043085602 0.0875  0.1375  0
>   17.23861185 0.071705699 0.15    0.1375  0
>   11.50832463     0.1125  0.0875  0.075
>   14.4810484  0.078476821 0.0375  0.125   0.0625
>   9.110262652 0.077306938 0.145   0.35    0.0125
>   10.8571733  0.02681341  0.0375  0.525   0
>   9.589339421 0.01892435  0.2275  0   0
>   7.260373588 0.014538237 0.425   0.25    0
>   11.11099161 0.022802578 0.225   0.3875  0
>   10.81488848 0.047587818 0.15    0.075   0
>   8.224131957 0.031126904 0.25    0.075   0
>   8.818607863 0.002855409 0.22    0.22    0
>   11.53999863 0.031465613 0.0375  0.35    0.225
>   14.92784964 0.069998663 0.0625  0.2625  0.225
>   9.666480932 0.02387741  0.1125  0.45    0.025
>   12.51000758 0.016960259 0.1625  0.525   0.0625
>   13.32611463 0.033670382 0.1875  0.35    0.1375
>   16.76535191 0.029613698 0.3375  0.3 0
>   11.24615281 0.008440059 0.0875  0.1375  0
>   10.60564875 0.003930792 0.15    0.1375  0
>   11.82909125 0.036017582 0.1125  0.0875  0.075
>   18.2337185  0.143451512 0.0375  0.125   0.0625
>   10.6226222  0.020561242 0.145   0.35    0.0125`

Excel gives the following output:

> ### Regression Statistics
>
> Multiple R = 0.420431825
>   R Square = 0.176762919
>   Adjusted R Square = 0.152550064
>   Standard Error = 3.054032651
>   Observations = 36
>
> ## ANOVA
>
> ```
>           df         SS           MS          F           Significance F
> ```
>
> Regression    1 / 68.0914386 / 68.0914386 / 7.300374813 / 0.010676279
>
> Residual      34 / 317.1219248 / 9.327115435
>
> Total 35 / 385.2133634
>
> ## Coefficients
>
> ```
>             Coefficients    Standard Er      t Stat       P-value
> ```
>
> Intercept       14.69082425   /  0.996953237  /   14.7357205  / 2.50758E-16
>
> Heather%        -13.78771857   / 5.102932589   /  -2.701920579 /  0.010676279
>
> ## Coefficients con't
>
> Lower95%     Upper 95%     Lower 95.0%    Upper 95.0%
>
> 12.66477151 / 16.71687699 /  12.66477151  / 16.71687699
>
> -24.15812531 / -3.41731183 /  -24.15812531    / -3.417311838

Whilst R gives the following output:

> HS <- lm(heather ~ suva, data=data1)
>    summary(HS)
>
> Call: lm(formula = heather ~ suva, data = data1)
>
> Residuals:
>
> ```
>   Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max
> ```
>
> -0.149941 / -0.063070 / -0.009812 / 0.038370 / 0.225804
>
> Coefficients:
>
> ```
>          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
> ```
>
> (Intercept) 0.326633   0.060733   5.378 5.54e-06
>   suva        -0.012820   0.004745  -2.702   0.0107 *
>
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 0.09313 on 34 degrees of freedom Multiple
>   R-squared:  0.1768,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.1526  F-statistic:   7.3 on
>   1 and 34 DF,  p-value: 0.01068

Why are they different in terms of their coefficients? Which one is correct?

Comment: Are you sure, absolutely sure, that you have not reversed one model relative to the other?

Comment: Not the question, but heather, sedge and sphagnum look like fractions or proportions to me, not percentages.

Answer (score 12):

**The difference between coefficients** is in the relation x versus y which is reversed in the one case.

Note that

- in your R case the coefficient relates to 'suva'
- and in your Excel case the coefficient relates to 'heather'.

see in the following code where R can get to *both* cases:

```
lm(suva ~ heather, data = as.data.frame(data))

Call:
lm(formula = suva ~ heather, data = as.data.frame(data))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      heather  
      14.65       -13.60  

> lm(heather ~suva, data = as.data.frame(data))

Call:
lm(formula = heather ~ suva, data = as.data.frame(data))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         suva  
    0.32524     -0.01276
```

rest of the code:

```
data <- c(
12.880545,   0.061156645, 0.15   , 0.525,   0,
7.098873327, 0.026878039, 0.2275,  0   ,0,
8.660688381, 0.04037841 , 0.425 ,  0.25 ,   0,
7.734546932, 0.021618446, 0.225 , 0.3875,  0,
16.70696048, 0.103626684, 0.15  ,  0.075,   0,
9.763315183, 0.013387158, 0.25  ,  0.075,   0,
12.91735434, 0.008076468, 0.22  ,  0.22 ,   0,
19.94153851, 0.150798057, 0.0375,  0.35 ,   0.225,
17.25115559, 0.052229596, 0.0625,  0.2625,  0.225,
15.38596941, 0.05429447 , 0.1125,  0.45 ,   0.025,
15.53714185, 0.05933884 , 0.1625,  0.525,   0.0625,
14.11551229, 0.064579437, 0.1875,  0.35 ,   0.1375,
14.88575569, 0.0189853  , 0.3375,  0.3, 0,
12.32229733, 0.043085602, 0.0875,  0.1375,  0,
17.23861185, 0.071705699, 0.15  ,  0.1375,  0,
11.50832463,     0.1125 , 0.0875,  0.075, 0,
14.4810484,  0.078476821, 0.0375,  0.125,   0.0625,
9.110262652, 0.077306938, 0.145 ,  0.35 ,   0.0125,
10.8571733,  0.02681341 , 0.0375,  0.525,   0,
9.589339421, 0.01892435 , 0.2275,  0  , 0,
7.260373588, 0.014538237, 0.425 ,  0.25 ,   0,
11.11099161, 0.022802578, 0.225 ,  0.3875 , 0,
10.81488848, 0.047587818, 0.15  ,  0.075  , 0,
8.224131957, 0.031126904, 0.25  ,  0.075  , 0,
8.818607863, 0.002855409, 0.22  ,  0.22   , 0,
11.53999863, 0.031465613, 0.0375,  0.35   , 0.225,
14.92784964, 0.069998663, 0.0625,  0.2625 , 0.225,
9.666480932, 0.02387741 , 0.1125,  0.45   , 0.025,
12.51000758, 0.016960259, 0.1625,  0.525  , 0.0625,
13.32611463, 0.033670382, 0.1875,  0.35   , 0.1375,
16.76535191, 0.029613698, 0.3375,  0.3 ,0,
11.24615281, 0.008440059, 0.0875,  0.1375,  0,
10.60564875, 0.003930792, 0.15  ,  0.1375,  0,
11.82909125, 0.036017582, 0.1125,  0.0875 , 0.075,
18.2337185,  0.143451512, 0.0375,  0.125  , 0.0625,
10.6226222,  0.020561242, 0.145 ,  0.35   , 0.0125
)
data <- matrix(data,36, byrow=1)
colnames(data) <- c("suva", "Std dev", "heather", "sedge",   "sphagnum")
```

---

**Why then, is $R^2$ still the same?**

There is a certain symmetry in the situation. The regression slope coefficient is (in [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression)) the correlation coefficient scaled by the variance of the $x$ and $y$ data.

$$\hat\beta_{y \sim x} = r_{xy} \frac{s_y}{s_x}$$

The regression model variance is then:

$$s_{mod} = \hat\beta_{y \sim x} s_x = r_{xy} s_y$$

and the ratio of model variance and variance of the data is:

$$R^2 = \left( \frac{s_{mod}}{s_y}  \right)^2= r_{xy}^2$$

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply. It has helped massively and has made the results now the same.